# Padding doesn't allow pseudo elements to create border-bottom

Tags: html, css, box-sizing

I try to create the border bottom radius for `h2` elements using pseudo elements.
But When I apply padding, top-left and top-right of border-bottom-radius were not reflected. But if I applied margin, it was reflected. I can't understand why this happen

```css
h2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
   padding-top: 5%;/* ---- top-left and top-right of border were not generated properly */
  /*margin-top: 5%; -------this works perfectly*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wrapper">
  <h1>Interior Design</h1>
  <div id="showcase">
    <h2>Showcase</h2>
    <div class="category_wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img-width col-md-6">
          <img src="img/atrium.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img-width col-md-6">
          <img src="img/kitchenconcrete.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this minimal code, margin or padding makes no difference. It should be something else.

Comment: try adding a `background` to the `:after` to see that the `border-radius` works but you only have `bottom-border` set right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused *why* the `border-radius` is not getting applied to the top left and top right areas whey you add `padding`:

[image]

It works even when you add `padding` - try adding a background to the `::after` element and you'll understand why (*hint*: you only have defined `bottom-border`):

```css
h2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wrapper">
  <h1>Interior Design</h1>
  <div id="showcase">
    <h2>Showcase</h2>
    <div class="category_wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img-width col-md-6">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img-width col-md-6">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want it to work with `padding`, simply add a background and border on *all* sides - see demo below:

```css
h2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); /* border on all sides */
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background: red; /* background with same color */
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wrapper">
  <h1>Interior Design</h1>
  <div id="showcase">
    <h2>Showcase</h2>
    <div class="category_wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="img-width col-md-6">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="img-width col-md-6">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ kukkuz... Thank you for your answer. I can understand what you did... But my doubt why top left and top right areas dont get raddius  is not clear.

Comment: that's because `border` is set *around* the  box `height` and `width`, `padding` of the box... but `margin` is *outside* the `border`...

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour. Your elements are pretty much shaped like an onion in layers. Starting from the outside it's margin - border - padding. As the border surrounds the padding, the padding pushes out the border. This means you create an inner square in your element (just consisting of the padding). This then leads to the effect, that your border-bottom is flat to the top (where it touches the inner square) and doesn't get the rounded borders.

I hope this helps explain what's happening here